# (quarkus-kafka) Deserialize complex object with nested complex objects in consumerRecord?

Tags: apache-kafka, deserialization, quarkus

In a quarkus application, We have a complex object with other complex objects as attributes and we need to deserialize this from a consumerRecord. here are the classes examples

'''

```
 @Data
 public class Person {
     private Hobbies hobbies;
     private List<Relatives> relatives;
 }

 @Data
 public class Hobbies {
    private Sports sports;
    private String principal;
 }

@Data
public class Parents {
  private Children kids;
  private String mom;
}
```

'''

We have a consumer to receive the message like this

'''

```
@Incoming("topic_test")
public void process(ConsumerRecord<String, Person> consumerRecord {
    log.info("Message key[{}] body [{}], consumerRecord.key(), consumerRecord.value());
    final var person = toPerson(consumerRecord::value);
    //call service
    ...
}

private Person toPerson(Callable<Person> callable) {
    try{
       return callable.call();
    } catch Exception(e) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

'''

and finally we got our properties file

'''

```
%prod.mp.messaging.incoming.topic_test.connector=smallrye-kafka
%prod.mp.messaging.incoming.topic_test.topic=test-topic
%prod.mp.messaging.incoming.topic_test.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer
%prod.mp.messaging.incoming.topic_test.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

'''
I´m not sure about those deserializer configuration if it´s correct for our scneario, but also I didn´t find any way to deserialize this object 'Person'. We´ve tried to change for ObjectMapperSerializer but got same exception every time. Also tried to change consumeRecord for byte[] and String but it didn´t worked too, when we tried to call readValue using object mapper it couldn´t deserialize the object correctly.

'''

```
A message sent to channel 'topic_test' has been nacked, fail-stop

A failure has been reported for Kafka topics [test-topic]: 
com.faster.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instace of 'projectpath'.Person (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

'''

Also, I noticed that now messages are no longer consumed and are stuck on the partition

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have default constructor in your model class Person in order for the deserialisation to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).